# Creating receipts with Stripe Orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I've looked at the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts) and found receipts that can be attached to `Charges` by simply passing in `receipt_email`. However, I have `Products` and `SKUs` that I need to attach `Orders` to. Simply creating a `Charge` doesn't suffice. What am I missing? This seems like a super basic use case. How does one go about selling a product on Stripe and sending a receipt?

Comment: For receipts you would either build your own or use a third-party

Comment: Is there a reason stripe receipts can't be applied to orders? That seems so ridiculous to me.

Comment: They are applied, but they won't fit your needs since they send a simple line item mentioning the order id and not the order's content for now.

Comment: But every order is associated to a product.

Comment: That is not something supported unfortunately. You have to build your own receipt logic or use a third-party.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your account is set up to do it automatically. Then, get the `Charge` ID from the `Order` and use it to update the `Charge` with a `receipt_email`.

Note that `Orders` API is deprecated.